# Suppose $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of linear map $T$ if and only if $\bar{\lambda}$ is eigenvalue of the $T^{*}$ with no additional special condition

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose $T$ is a linear operator on the $V$($V$ is a real or complex inner product space),  $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of linear map $T$ if and only if $\bar{\lambda}$ is eigenvalue of the $T^{*}$.

I searched at the MSE, there are proof in the form of matrix and I understand it. But when use the following method:
$<Av_1,v_2>=\lambda_{1}<v_1,v_2>=<v_1,\bar{\lambda_{1}}v_2>$
And $<Av_1,v_2>=<v_1,A^{*}v_2>$
And use it maybe $A^{*}v_2=\bar{\lambda_{1}}v_2$ can  be proved. But I don't understand why $A^{*}v_2=\bar{\lambda_{1}}v_2$ in the last step.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the answer that uses this process? Like you mentioned, this question has been asked (and solved before) in this site; in fact, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431546/eigenvalues-of-adjoint-operator-general-case) is a very good solution by Sheldon Axler.

Comment: Thank you for your link. Maybe it can be proved by matrix, I have seen a proof just by the method I mentioned above, I try to find the link but I can not find it again :(, it just prove it as I mentioned above.@Carlo

Comment: By definition, the adjoint is the unique linear operator (or matrix) satisfying $\langle Tv, w \rangle = \langle v, T^* w \rangle$ for all vectors $v, w \in V.$ But in the equation you mention, it seems that $v_1$ is fixed, so I don’t see how to conclude that $A^* v_2 = \bar \lambda_1 v_2.$

Comment: You can use your method to prove the equivalence if you assume a finite dimension and that T is normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your method for the case of $V$ with finite dimension and if A is a normal matrix. So, you showed that
$$
\langle v_1,\bar\lambda v_2 \rangle = \langle \lambda v_1, v_2 \rangle = \langle Av_1, v_2 \rangle = \langle v_1,A^*v_2 \rangle.$$
Now, take $v_2$ as an eigenvector of $A^*$ so that
$$
\langle v_1,\bar\lambda v_2 \rangle = \langle v_1,A^*v_2 \rangle = \langle v_1,\lambda' v_2 \rangle, \text{ hence}
$$

$$
\langle v_1,v_2(\lambda' - \bar\lambda) \rangle = \overline{(\lambda' - \bar\lambda)} \langle v_1,v_2 \rangle = 0.
$$
Finally, since we are assuming that $V$ has finite dimension, we know that one of the eigenvectors of $A^*$ is not orthogonal to $v_1$, from which it follows that $\lambda'=\bar\lambda$. Note that here we use the fact that $A$ is normal, therefore, the eigenvectors form a basis, so we use this to conclude that one of the eigenvectos is not orthogonal.

Comment: Why is it true that one of the eigenvectors of $A^*$ is not orthogonal to $v_1?$

Comment: You are right, this is not obvious, only if we assume that all eigevalues are distinct. I will reformulate the answer, I think there is a better way.

Comment: Fixed the answer. I needed to add the normality of the matrix for it to work.